# Linq: Group By didn't generate Group by Sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

i'm trying to do a group by in linq to entities in c# but the generated query didn't include a group by within it only generated selects

Linq:

```
IQueryable<EntityDataView> data = (from a in ctx.EntityDataViews
                                                        select a);

IQueryable<viewClass> groupedData = (from x in data
                                                       group x by new
                                                       {
                                                           x.Id,
                                                           x.Code,
                                                           x.Name,
                                                           x.Amuont,

                                                       } into g
                                                       orderby g.Key.Amuont descending
                                                       select new viewClass()
                                                       {
                                                           Id = g.Key.Id,
                                                           Code = g.Key.Code,
                                                           Name = g.Key.Name,
                                                           Amuont = g.Key.Amuont,
                                                       });
```

SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Code] AS [Code], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Amuont] AS [Amuont]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
    [Extent1].[Amuont] AS [Amuont], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    FROM [dbo].[EntityDataView] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Amuont] DESC
```

Comment: Could you show us your model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It didn't create a `GROUP BY`, because it is not necessary. You are using `group into`, you are not iterating the group and you are not aggregating any values. If `Id` is your unique identitiy column, you are not even creating groups, since there will be only one item per group. That is essentially the same as a simple select.

You have to accept that EF will create an SQL query based on its own evaluation of the LINQ query. Those queries can differ. The only guarantee that you have is that they produce the same result.

Comment: Nice answer (especially the `Id` part! EF is indeed smart enough to remove unnecessary operators based on metadata.

Comment: yep it was about the aggregate function ,i forgot to add the Count()

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is no group by, because you don't iterate over the elements in each group.

The nice thing about IQueryable is that it is quite smart in optimizing your query. If you first add an element in your query and later get rid of it, you won't see it in your SQL:

```
var myItems = items.Select(item => new
{
    X = item.A,
    Y = item.B,
    Z = item.C,
})
.Select(item => new
{
    X = item.A,
    Z = item.C,
});
```

You won't see the select of B in your SQL query, IQueryable is smart enough to see that you don't want it.

By the way, it seems that you want all unique values of {Id, Code, Name, Amount}. For this it is faster to use [Enumerable.Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct(v=vs.110).aspx) than GroupBy.

Comment: In SQL `GROUP BY` is not necessary slower than `DISTINCT`. Replace one by the other and you get the same execution plan (in indexed views you even need to use `GROUP BY`, because `DISTINCT` is forbidden). And in the LINQ query it doesn't matter, because it is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to bring the most biggest amount lines from your group.
Please try this;

```
IQueryable<viewClass> groupedData = (from x in data
                   group x by new
                   {
                       x.Code,
                       x.Name

                   } into g
                   select new viewClass()
                   {
                       Id = gp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Amuont).FirstOrDefault().Id,
                       Code = g.Key.Code,
                       Name = g.Key.Name,
                       Amuont = g.Max(_=>_.Amuont)
                   });
```